# Optimizing SQL query in MySQL one table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have this problem, I'm making this query but is taking too long, like 10 seconds to find 95 records

`SELECT * FROM tbl_factura WHERE dateFechaHora >= '2018-04-01' AND dateFechaHora <= '2018-04-30' AND intTimbrada = 1 AND intCancelada = 0 AND cfdi_33 = 1 AND RFC_usuario = 'FRANCISCOI10'`

`mysql> show indexes from tbl_factura;`

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tbl_factura |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | idFactura           | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_idContador      |            1 | idContador          | A         |        3875 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_dateFechaHora   |            1 | dateFechaHora       | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_intTimbrada     |            1 | intTimbrada         | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_intCancelada    |            1 | intCancelada        | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_idContadorSub   |            1 | idContadorSub       | A         |         113 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_intFolio        |            1 | intFolio            | A         |       21139 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_formaPago       |            1 | strFormaPago        | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_email_enviado   |            1 | email_enviado       | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_cfdi33          |            1 | cfdi_33             | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_intStatus       |            1 | intStatus           | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_status          |            1 | intStatus           | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_serie           |            1 | strSerie            | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_rfc_usuario     |            1 | RFC_usuario         | A         |        1875 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_facturaexcel    |            1 | facturaExcel        | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_razonSocial     |            1 | CH_razon_social     | A         |       58133 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_nombreComercial |            1 | CH_nombre_comercial | A         |        2397 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_RFC             |            1 | CH_RFC              | A         |       38755 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto1      |            1 | idFactura           | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto1      |            2 | idContador          | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto1      |            3 | cfdi_33             | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto2      |            1 | idContador          | A         |        2835 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto2      |            2 | cfdi_33             | A         |        4471 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto3      |            1 | dateFechaHora       | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto3      |            2 | intTimbrada         | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto3      |            3 | intCancelada        | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto3      |            4 | cfdi_33             | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto3      |            5 | RFC_usuario         | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto4      |            1 | RFC_usuario         | A         |        3633 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto4      |            2 | intTimbrada         | A         |        4306 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto4      |            3 | intCancelada        | A         |        6459 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_compuesto4      |            4 | cfdi_33             | A         |        9301 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura |          1 | idx_folio_fiscal    |            1 | strFolioFiscal      | A         |      232534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

This table have about 254,809 records, we have bigger tables with more complex queries and they dont take long time, this is the explain of the query

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tbl_factura
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_dateFechaHora,idx_intTimbrada,idx_intCancelada,idx_cfdi33,idx_rfc_usuario,idx_compuesto3,idx_compuesto4
          key: idx_compuesto4
      key_len: 64
          ref: const,const,const,const
         rows: 493
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.45 sec)
```

so I would like to know if you can see something bad on this data and help me out to find a better way to do this if is possible, is there something wrong with the index this query is taking? I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: My intuition at first glance is to add `dateFechaHora` to the end of the `idx_compuesto4` index. _Alternatively, perhaps try forcing `idx_dateFechaHora` to see if perhaps your data happens to query better with it in this case._

Comment: Strange. Index idx_compuesto4 would have been my choice, too. 10 seconds seem too long. Maybe it's because of fragmentation? Read here on how to defrag: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html

Comment: @Uueerdo I will try this

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I will try this later and see if it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of interest are the columns `dateFechaHora`, `intTimbrada`, `intTimbrada`, `cfdi_33` and `RFC_usario` as they are used in the `WHERE`of your query. `idx_compuesto4` looks good in general. But try and include `dateFechaHora` also.

Assuming the statistics are recent (to be sure run [`ANALYZE TABLE tbl_factura;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html)) the indexes on the individual columns in the list of your indexes tell, that there are (roughly) 232534 distinct values for `dateFechaHora`. For `intTimbrada`, `intTimbrada` and `cfdi_33` it's 5 for each of them. And for `RFC_usario` there are 1875 distinct values.

Further assuming, that all values of each column is more or less "evenly distributed" (i.e. for column `x` there are *n* distinct values in the table and all partitions induced by `x` have a similar cardinality), `intTimbrada`, `intTimbrada` and `cfdi_33` are not very selective. So, if we include them in a compound index, they should go last.

For `dateFechaHora` it's not so easy, because the query asks for a range. But an ascending index can help to quickly partition the set of records into those records, that have a lower value than the minimum of the range and those, that have a higher value than it. Looking at your query I noticed, that you wanted the invoices (that's what that table holds, I guessed?) due the last month. Other guesses are, that this is the usual case (the months "roll" as time goes forward) and that you have a lot of invoices due in the past but comparatively few in the future. That is, the number of due dates, that are greater than the range's maximum is far smaller than the number of them being less than its minimum. In other words taking the partition of those invoices with a due date greater than the minimum of the range, which we can get quickly from the index, and filtering out the few where the due date is greater than the maximum isn't a too bad approach.

But I had a little problem with `dateFechaHora`. I noticed, the cardinality of `idx_dateFechaHora` is equal to the one of `PRIMARY`. So I guess `dateFechaHora` is a `datetime` and `dateFechaHora` differs even for invoices due the same day. It gave me a little headache what that 232534 would be in distinct months, so I'm a little unsure for the order of `dateFechaHora` and `RFC_usario`. I guessed it's more likely, that you have less users (`RFC_usario` is the user, right?), than months you are in business. So I suppose `dateFechaHora` should probably go first. Then `RFC_usario`, because its selectivity is much better than that of the others, second and then the others.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_compuesto5
             ON (dateFechaHora,
                 RFC_usuario,
                 intTimbrada,
                 intCancelada,
                 cfdi_33);
```

You can also try and interchange the order of `dateFechaHora` and `RFC_usuario`, if that's better. As I said above I'm not too certain on that.

Including the relatively "bad" columns `intTimbrada`, `intCancelada` and `cfdi_33` has the disadvantage of making the index larger. That is, they could make the difference between the index fitting (largely) in memory and the opposite. Hence, without them, disk IO might be less overall, which of course is better. So maybe you want to try to kick them out, if that's the case.

Of course this can all be wrong, as I know nothing about the data. For example there are maybe only very few records where `cfdi_33 = 1`. That could make `cfdi_33` very good. If the optimizer of MySQL can play on that level. I don't know that. You might want to think about that too.

Comment: Can you explain about the order of the columns? I will try to add this index

Comment: This worked for me, and thank you for the explanation, this new index make the difference.